# Why do Shapefiles and GeoJSON behave differently in GDAL Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, geojson

I have a `test.shp`. I loop over the file, buffer the features, and write the buffers to a new file. I tested writing the buffers to a  Shapefile and to a GeoJSON. If I try to use the new buffer layer afterwards, for example to get a feature count, I get a number for the Shapefile `90 features`, but not for the GeoJSON `0 features`. What is the reason for that?

The code looks like this

```
import ogr
test = ogr.Open('test.shp', 0)
lyrTest = test.GetLayer()
```

For the Shapefile

```
shpdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = shpdriver.CreateDataSource('Buffer.shp')
lyrBuffer = ds.CreateLayer('buffer', geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
featureDefn = lyrBuffer.GetLayerDefn()

featureTest = lyrTest.GetNextFeature()
while featureTest:
  geomTest = featureTest.GetGeometryRef()
  geomBuffer = geomTest.Buffer(250)
  outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
  outFeature.SetGeometry(geomBuffer)
  lyrBuffer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
  outFeature.Destroy()
  featureTest = lyrTest.GetNextFeature()

print lyrBuffer.GetFeatureCount()
```

For the GeoJSON

```
GeoJSONdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GeoJSON')
ds = GeoJSONdriver.CreateDataSource('Buffer.geojson')
lyrBuffer = ds.CreateLayer('Buffer.geojson', geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
featureDefn = lyrBuffer.GetLayerDefn()

featureTest = lyrTest.GetNextFeature()
while featureTest:
  geomTest = featureTest.GetGeometryRef()
  geomBuffer = geomTest.Buffer(250)
  outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
  outFeature.SetGeometry(geomBuffer)
  lyrBuffer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
  outFeature.Destroy()
  featureTest = lyrTest.GetNextFeature()

print lyrBuffer.GetFeatureCount()
```

Comment: Probably some slightly different implementation in the backend. If you want the same behaviour, you'll need to reset reading afterwards.

Comment: @BradHards If I add `lyrBuffer.ResetReading()` I still get `0` features.

Comment: OK, sorry for the bad suggestion. The only other thing I can think of is changing the second argument to Open()

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'second argument to Open()'? Do you mean to close the data source and then reopen it?

Comment: A call to the Open() method (like "ogr.Open('test.shp', 0)") has two arguments. I meant "the second argument".

Comment: That doesn't make a difference either.

Comment: It looks like the GeoJSON driver is unable to correctly use `ResetReading()` for a created dataset. I'd call this a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gross, but:

```
del lyrBuffer
del ds  # flushes Buffer.geojson to disk
ds = GeoJSONDriver.Open('Buffer.geojson', 0)
lyrBuffer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
print lyrBuffer.GetFeatureCount()
```

From what I can tell, `OGRGeoJSONDataSource.CreateLayer()` returns a `OGRGeoJSONWriteLayer`, not a `OGRGeoJSONLayer` (which is what you get when opening an existing file). The former doesn't implement `GetFeatureCount()` (or much other useful stuff), and the datasource doesn't (a) actually flush the file to disk until it's deleted (ignoring `SyncToDisk()`)or (b) expose any of the private methods that do flush it or enable proper re-reading of the layer.

By contrast, the Shapefile driver uses a single layer class for both reading and writing, and changes are propagated much better when you're editing.

Normally [Fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona) is a nicer python-based interface to OGR, but in this case it still requires reloading the file:

```
import fiona

with fiona.open('test.shp', 'r') as source:
    with fiona.open('Buffer.geojson', 'w',
                    crs=source.crs,
                    driver="GeoJSON",
                    schema=source.schema) as sink:

        for f in source:
            sink.write(f)

with fiona.open('Buffer.geojson', 'r') as sink:
    print len(sink)
```

Comment: Yep. GeoJSON is all about putting features on the wire. A GeoJSON file is not a lightweight database and anyone trying to use it for that (instead of using shapefiles, etc) is going to get tripped up.